# How should I mock a Redis connection in Go when the connection is in a struct?

Tags: unit-testing, go, redis

I'm writing a Go module that deals with storing some custom metrics to a data store. The nature of the data makes Redis ideal, but it makes sense to use interfaces just in case needs change. I have the following code:

```
type MetricsStore interface {
    Put(metric string) (string, error)
    Get(id string) (string, error)
}
```

I then have a struct that contains a Redis client, and a `New()` function which creates an instance of the struct and instantiates the Redis client using the parameters passed into the function.

```
type MetricsRedisCache struct {
    c *redis.Client
}

func New(address string, password string, db int) (MetricsRedisCache) {
    options := &redis.Options{
        Addr:               address,
        Password:           password,
        DB:                 db,
    }

    return RedisUrlStore{client: redis.NewClient(options)}
}
```

MetricsRedisCache then implements the functions defined on the MetricsStore interface. The issue here is that since the `New()` function creates the Redis client and returns it inside of the `MetricsRedisCache` struct, I can't easily create a mock client to use when writing Unit tests for the `Put()` and `Get()` functions that take `MetricsRedisCache` through the receiver.

Comment: You may want to implement a repository pattern and mock that one, leaving the test of the Repository with Mongo to the Integration Test stage.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini I'm not currently planning to use Mongo, the only storage being used at this point is Redis.

Comment: Apologies, mistyped - I meant Redis (does not really change the approach I proposed, does it? :))

Comment: The `New` function is irrelevant - if it doesn't create what you want in a test, you just don't use it to create instances for your tests. To make the Redis client mockable, you'd define an interface with the methods you use on `redis.Client`, and then make the `c` field of the interface type.

Comment: @Adrian's comment should be selected as the answer. You don't create functions in production code just to use them in tests. Just instantiate the client directly in your tests or move your second constructor IN the tests files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new constructor, `NewWithClient` or some such that takes the client as a parameter instead of creating it. It then returns a `MetricsRedisCache` using the given client. You can use this constructor in your tests to exercise the logic of `MetricsRedisCache` using a mock Redis client.

Comment: Thanks! In your opinion, do you think it'd be better to leave the NewWithClient as an unexported function (so `newWithClient`)? One of my reasons for having the client contained within the `MetricsRedisCache` struct (and unexported) was to prevent the client from being reused outside of the functions defined within my package.

Comment: @ChardeeMacdennis: yes, if this constructor is used only for unit tests, keeping it unexported is a good idea. You can always decided to export it later if needed, but the reverse is more difficult.